# regular expressions match/groups

Tags: python, regex, match

I have been trying to learn about auto segmentation so I found a code on github but I can't figure out why it won't run. I don't understand `rs = re.match('.+', str(p))` when I run this line it gets a match and moves on to `patient_images[file][rs.groups()[0]] = p` but then I get the error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I printed out `rs` and get `None`. Why am I getting `None`?

image directory is structured like this:

```
code:
    patients:
        pat01:
            images:
                export1.dcm
                export2.dcm
                export3.dcm
            masks:
                export1.dcm
                export2.dcm
                export3.dcm
```

code:

```
import os, re

root_dir = f"C:/Users/user/Desktop/code/patients/"
patient_images = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.dcm'):
            if 'PATIENT_DICOM' in root:
            if not patient_images.get(file,None):
                patient_images[file] = {}
            p = os.path.join(root,file)
            patient_images[file]['real'] = p

            elif 'masks' in root:
                print(os.path.join(root,file))
                if not patient_images.get(file,None):
                    patient_images[file] = {}
                p = os.path.join(root,file)
                rs = re.match('.*MASKS_DICOM/(.*)/.*', str(p))
                if rs:
                    patient_images[file][rs.groups()[0]] = p
                    print('match')
                else:
                    print('Did not match groups')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `rs = re.match(...)` you want `rs.group()` (note there's no 's') which is the part of the string that matched.

Also, a regex of '.+' will match all strings that have at least one character so it'd be neater to write:

```py
p = os.path.join(root,file)
if len(p) > 0:
    patient_images[file][p] = p
```

Comment: I just noticed that `'.+'` was an edit that I made in an attempt to make the code work. The original string was `rs = re.match('.*masks/(.*)/.*', str(p))` the output of rs when it is run like this is `None`.

Comment: Ah, cool. The output of that regex is None because it doesn't match the string. Your path is `"pat01/masks/export1.dcm"` but that regex wants `"masks/something/something_else"